# Ignore CheckInvalidPathChars

Tags: c#

I know you probably shouldn't do this, but I was wondering how it would be possible to ignore the `CheckInvalidPathChars` check in `System.IO.Path` throughout the whole program. Given the fact that the `Path` class is static, you can't just override the method.

I'd like my program to be able to run from locations as `C:\PRN`.

Reference: [`CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, bool checkAdditional = false)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,5c0b2030676e9f3e)

Comment: FWIW you can click the line numbers (amongst other things) in Reference Source to get [links right to the bit you want](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,5c0b2030676e9f3e).

Comment: FileStream and Path are a little too picky, you can't use them if you want to use long paths, talk to a device, access an alternate file stream, use a name that matches a legacy DOS device name.  Not entirely without reason, it limits the number of support calls and made CAS easier to implement.  You still can, you'll have to pinvoke CreateFile().

Answer (score 1):

You can't and you shouldn't.

Those characters aren't prohibited by the .NET Framework, but by the underlying operating system. You can't save a file there when using any of the characters specified in the invalid path characters.

If you want to have a 'file name' that is invalid, you have to do all operations by hand.

(And by the way, `C:\PRN` is a valid path according to the rules)

Comment: What is the error you get and why do you think it is related to these characters?